# video background responsive 480p 720p 1080p

Tags: html, video, background

Hello i am trying to display a video in the background but the resolution changes when the window becomes smaller for uses less data to load it on mobile and tablet.

My video formats: .mp4 - .webm - .ogv - 30sec loop.

480p - 6mb for mobile

720p - 10mb for tablet

1080p to 2k - 15mb-25mb for pc

My CSS:

```
    video#bgvid-480p {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/480p.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

    video#bgvid-720p {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/720p.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

    video#bgvid-1080p {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/1080p.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

video { 
display: block; 
}
```

My Code:

```
<video autoplay loop poster="images/480p.jpg" id="bgvid-480p">
<source src="medias/480p.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="medias/480p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="medias/480p.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<video autoplay loop poster="images/720p.jpg" id="bgvid-720p">
<source src="medias/720p.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="medias/720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="medias/720p.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

<video autoplay loop poster="images/1080p.jpg" id="bgvid-1080p">
<source src="medias/1080p.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="medias/1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="medias/1080p.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

What is the best solution to automatically change the video if the window is smaller. Js or css? I want to keep this basic code but I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check out this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/video-source-by-screen-size/

As it points out you could use the media attribute of the sources but this didn't work for me.
What i came up with is this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var width = screen.width;

    var quality = "480p";
    if (width > 480 && width <= 720) { quality = "720p"; }
    if (width > 720) { quality = "1080p"; }

    document.getElementById("bgvid").innerHTML = "<source type='video/webm' src='" + quality + ".webm' />\
    <source type='video/mp4' src='" + quality + ".mp4' />\
    <source type='video/ogv' src='" + quality + ".ogv' />";
}
```

in a script tag in the header, and

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid"></video>
```

in the body.

It should be self explanatory!

Simon

Answer (score 1):

Well Simon, I tested your code and it works better in fact and it's really simple. I just added style block and changed width > 480 to 380 to display 720p, if not the iPhone 5-6 got the 480p. Now everything is perfect.  :)  Thanks a lot!

Here is my final code for those who would like to get it!

Head section:

```
<style type="text/css">
    video#bgvid {
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/bg-video.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    video { 
    display: block; 
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var width = screen.width;

        var quality = "480p";
        if (width > 380 && width <= 720) { quality = "720p"; }
        if (width > 720) { quality = "1080p"; }

        document.getElementById("bgvid").innerHTML = "<source type='video/webm' src='medias/" + quality + ".webm' />\
        <source type='video/mp4' src='medias/" + quality + ".mp4' />\
        <source type='video/ogv' src='medias/" + quality + ".ogv' />";
    }
</script>
```

Body section:

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid"></video>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a combination of html5 and Javascript. in the following external page Chris shows you how to do this exact same thing with actually less code. Good luck!

https://css-tricks.com/video-source-by-screen-size/

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that 480 and 720 are measurements of video *height* — not width. 
A 720p video is 1280px wide by 720 high.

So for the breakpoints it should be:

```
var quality = "480p";
if (width > 640 && width <= 720) { quality = "720p"; }
if (width > 1280) { quality = "1080p"; }
```

Great code though! Just used it a project.